# Properties of a subspace of sequence

Tags: analysis

Let $p\in\left[  1,\infty\right)  $ and $\left(
X_{0},\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{p}\right)  $ a normed linear space, where
$$
X_{0}=\left\{  \left(  x_{n}\right)  \in
\mathbb{R}
^{
\mathbb{N}
}\mid\exists n_{0}\in%
\mathbb{N}
,\forall n\in
\mathbb{N}
:n_{0}\geq n\Rightarrow x_{n}=0\right\}  .
$$

Let the subspace
$$
A=\left\{  \left(  x_{n}\right)  \in X_{0}\mid\forall n\in%
\mathbb{N}
:\left\vert x_{n}\right\vert \leq\frac{1}{n}\right\}  .
$$
Show that $A$ is closed, absorbing and find the set $\operatorname{int}A$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  You should update your question to include information about what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: A is closed: you only need to prove that $A_{n}=\left\{  \left(  x_{n}\right)  \in X_{0}\mid\left\vert x_{n}\right\vert \leq\frac{1}{n}\right\} $ is closed

Comment: A is absorbing: let $(x_{n})\in X_{0}$. If $n>N$ implies $x_{n}=0$, then $(x_{n})\in\max_{n\leq N}\{nx_{n}\}\cdot A$